# Negotiation timed out - issue with windows IKE2 VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

This is a complete new one for me.

We've got a VPN (cert based) running happily on the domain. However after a while of working ok (and usually after I get to home to the other side of town) I find I cannot connect to the VPN anymore.

**The following error occurred in the Point to Point Protocol module on port: VPN1-125, UserName: . Negotiation timed out.**

Obvioulsy I've googled a bit but I cannot seem to understand what to do. Has anyone come across this issue and resolved it please?

I'm not a sysadmin (we are a three man company) but it's only me it seems to happen to. The other two use windows 7 professsional as client while I use windows 7 ultimate. All the machines are on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Have you completely blocked ICMP on your home firewall?  Has your home ISP blocked all ICMP traffic?

See [What might prevent IKE handshake success in building an IPSEC tunnel?](https://serverfault.com/questions/283732/what-might-prevent-ike-handshake-success-in-building-an-ipsec-tunnel)

It is mostly about Cisco VPN, but the same things will affect any IPSEC VPN.